# Create a text file and writing vector in that file

Tags: file, matlab, function

I am currently trying to create a function in Matlab

```
Function[output]=store(filename,vector)
```

It's supposed to create a text file with the name (filename) and write vector(i) on line i in the text file.

But how do I create a textfile from within a function?

Comment: Have you tried `fopen` and `fwrite`?

Comment: Use option `'a'` with `fopen` to create the file. See other options with `help fopen`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
 dlmwrite(filename, vector(:))
```

The (:) operator reshape the vector to make sure it is a column vector, not a row vector. It may or may not be necessary (also, it will cause problems if you pass in a matrix, because it will be reshaped into a vector).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, which gives no output:

```
function store(filename,vector)

vector = vector(:); % make column vector
save(filename,'-ascii','vector');
```

If you need a successful/unsuccessful output, you can wrap the `save` statement in a `try`-`catch` block:

```
function output = store(filename,vector)

vector = vector(:); % make column vector
try
    output = 1; % successful
    save(filename,'-ascii','vector');
catch
    output = 0; % unsuccesfull
end
```